# Wifi Hotspot in android can communicate with pc without the wifi router

Tags: java, android, sockets, wifi, android-wifi

Iam newbie in android, without a wifi router in pc i want to connect wifi hotspot in android to the pc? 
Is that possible to make connection by putting mobile hotspot on and find the ip address of android hotspot and can i make a connection with pc without a wifi router in java ?

Comment: Here in that article every device have wifi hotspot so they can have the communication through ip. My question is through mobile hotspot to pc communication is possible without wifi router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do have any wifi module in your PC, then yes, you could set wifi hotspot on your Android device, get it a name and password (optionally), search for avaliable wifi networks on PC and connect to it.

Comment: If i automatically enable the hotspot on android and take the ip of the hotspot and can i just implement with socket programming with that ip. will it work or am i totally wrong?